# Java Sellinum Cucumber Excell data driven

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

Need to get "value" based on given "key" from Excel file
I have excel file
File name Test xlsx
and sheet  name sheet1

And sheet contains following key and value pairs and. JIRA ticket is unique  .

| Test case description | testdata key | Testdatavalue | testdata2 key | Testdata2 Value | testdata3 key | Testdata3 value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sampiletest description1 | Testcase-jira-1 | user1id | Harshadh | Password | 123ggg |  |
| Sampiletest2 discription | Testcase-jira-2 | user2 | Ramu | Password123 | 333ggg |  |
| Sampiletest3 discription | Test case jira-3 | user3 | latha | Password556 | 73hhh |  |

Up to N number of rows

Here, I needs to get the data in following way by using Java Selenium Cucumber. I am going to use above test data to pass in `Cucumber step definition` class file by BDD way.

How can we get the data in `definition` file for following way
1)If pass Key value from current row how can we get the value of value for provide test input for webSeleinum element
Example 4th row data

```
Sampiletest3 discription|Test case jira-3| user3|latha|Password556|73hhh
.....
```

If I call the "user3" that should return "Password556"
Same way any row I need to get the value.
Please guide me

Comment: Basically you want to read data from excel using cucumber scenario outline options. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes i need to get key and value format
Example My sheet row having
Username|user1|password| Password info|contry|India
.......if cal key country and results need India.. if I pass password then get password info ... Similar way all rows..

Comment: Why can't you read data from excel? In feature file, you can give the `worbookname` and `sheetName` and you can write a method to read data from excel. It is a good way to do because in future it will be difficult for you to maintain large data in `feature` files. Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Yes.. can you provide references for sampile

Comment: Posted an answer. Please see and respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below code.

**Feature file:**

- In examples, you can give the row numbers and sheet name to use the data for itterations.

```
    Scenario Outline: Login to the application with multiple users.
    
        Given get data from datasheet with "<test_id>" and "<sheetName>"
        And login to the application
    
        Examples: 
          | test_id | sheetName   |
          |       1 | Login       |
          |       2 | Login       |
```

**Excel data:**

[image]

**Read the data from excel and store it in a `hashmap`:**

- Create a class to read the data (Example: ExcelReader)
- Use `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` and `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel` imports

```
    
    public class ExcelReader {
    
        private File file;
        private FileInputStream inputStream;
        private String testID;
        private String sheetName;
        private int testIdColumn;
        private int numberOfColumns;
        private XSSFCell cell;
        public  HashMap<String, String> fieldsAndValues;
    
        public ExcelReader(String testId, String sheetName) {
            file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "Excel location path");
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found at given location: " + e);
            }
            this.testID = testId;
            this.sheetName = sheetName;
    
            this.readExcelAndCreateHashMapForData();
        }
    
        public HashMap<String, String> readExcelAndCreateHashMapForData() {
            try {
                fieldsAndValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    
                XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
    
                /* Get number of rows */
                int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
                int numberOfRows = lastRow - firstRow;
    
                /*
                 * Get test_Id column number.
                 */
                outerloop: for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++) {
                    numberOfColumns = sheet.getRow(row).getLastCellNum();
                    for (int cellNumber = 0; cellNumber < numberOfColumns; cellNumber++) {
                        cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(cellNumber);
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        if (sheet.getRow(row).getCell(cellNumber).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("test_ID")) {
                            testIdColumn = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(cellNumber).getColumnIndex();
                            break outerloop;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                /*
                 * Search for the test id value.
                 */
                outerloop: for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {
                    
                    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(testIdColumn);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    
                    if (testID.equals(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(testIdColumn).getStringCellValue())) {
    
                        
                        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; j++) {
                            XSSFCell key = sheet.getRow(testIdColumn).getCell(j);
                            XSSFCell value = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
    
                            key.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    
                            if (value == null) {
                                // Not capturing blank cells.
                            } else if (value.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                                // Not capturing blank cells.
                            } else {
                                value.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                String fieldName = sheet.getRow(testIdColumn).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().trim();
                                String fieldValue = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().trim();
                                fieldsAndValues.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("Fields and values: " + Arrays.toString(fieldsAndValues.entrySet().toArray()));
                        break outerloop;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred at getting the sheet: " + e);
            }
            /* Return the hash map */
            return fieldsAndValues;
        }
    
    }
```

**StepDefinition:**

```
         ExcelReader excelReader;
    
        @Given("get data from datasheet with \"(.*)\" and \"(.*)\"$")
            public void get_data_from_datasheet(String testId, String sheetName) {            
            excelReader = new ExcelReader(testId, sheetName);
            }
    

     @And("login to the application")
        public void loginApplication(){      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("element")).sendKeys(excelReader.fieldsAndValues.get("UserName"));         
driver.findElement(By.xpath("element")).sendKeys(excelReader.fieldsAndValues.get("PassWord"));      
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("element")).click();  
        }
```

Comment: Thank you@Nandan ... Hear your answer seems to near to the my solution... ... I have 10 feture files and  based on order of feature file I ll keep same order of test data in excel... But  hear I donot want pass data like id and sheet ... That data needs to get directly based on feature file and order of excel file data... Just I'll pass column value and that should needs to get value .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting all the data for a scenario inside of Gherkin documents, but you might have a valid use cases for pulling data from excel. However, in my experience, these type of requirements are rare. The reason why it is not recommended is, your BDD feature files are your requirements and should contain the right level of information to document the expected behavior of the system. If your data comes from an excel, then it just makes the requirement reading bit more difficult and makes it difficult to maintain.

Saying that if there is a strong reason for you to have these data stored in excel, you could easily achieve this using NoCodeBDD. All you have to do is map the column names and upload the excel and the tool take care of the rest. Please check this .gif to see how it is done. https://nocodebdd.live/examples-using-excel

Disclaimer: I am the founder of NoCodeBDD.

If you are using Junit5 here is an example on how it is done https://newbedev.com/data-driven-testing-in-cucumber-using-excel-files-code-example

Comment: If you think my answer has helped, would you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use external data-source to provide examples using [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber). It will enable to provide data-file to be used to provide examples from external data-source, which includes `csv`, `json`, `xml`, `excel` file or database query.

Answer (score 0):

> We cannot directly integrete Excel file data to Gerkin file

.
**Instead** write separate method in step file to get data from excel and do your cases.

I use following code get the data - common code

```
public static JSONArray Read_Excel_Data(String filename, String sheetname) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    Workbook workbookout = null;
    JSONArray totalData = new JSONArray();
    try{
        log.info("Filename and Sheet name  : "+filename+", "+ sheetname );
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        workbookout = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
        Sheet sh = workbookout.getSheet(sheetname);
        int totRows = sh.getLastRowNum();
        Row hearderRow = sh.getRow(0);
        int totCols = hearderRow.getLastCellNum();


        log.info("Total [ Rows and Colums ]  : [ "+totRows+" and "+ totCols +" ] ");
        for(int i=1; i <= totRows; i++ ){
            log.info("Progressing row : "+i);
            Row tempRw = sh.getRow(i);
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

            for(int j=0; j<totCols; j++ ){
                Cell tempCell = tempRw.getCell(j);
                Cell HeaderCell = hearderRow.getCell(j);
                try{
                    jo.put(HeaderCell.getStringCellValue(), tempCell.getStringCellValue());
                    log.info("Value in "+i+" / "+j+"             :::::::::::: >   "+tempCell.getStringCellValue() );
                }catch (NullPointerException npe){
                    log.warn(":::::::::::: > Null Value in [ "+i+" / "+j+" ] ");
                }
            }
            totalData.add(jo);
        }
        workbookout.close();
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println("Total data ::::::::  "+totalData.toJSONString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Error Occured !!"+e.toString());
        workbookout.close();
        fileIn.close();
    }
    return totalData;
}
```