# Is my approach to do cross browser tests in parallel based on user choice of browser from an excel sheet correct?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cross-browser, ui-automation

I have a situation and am looking for the best way to solve it and hence seeking everyone's suggestions.

I want to build a framework where a user can define all the test cases in excel sheet and against each test case user can define if he wants to run it or not and what browser it should run in. For each test case user can mention multiple browsers.

Now once I have this excel, I want the framework to run tests in parallel on desired browsers as mentioned in excel sheet.

I am thinking of few possible ways but need suggestions to optimise the approach:

Approach 1) define everything in excel then using POI APIs read excel data and create testng suite file with parameter and parallel options dynamically and run the formed testng suite.

Approach 2) defined everything in an excel sheet and then using data providers and parallel options read data from excel sheet and pass to @Test method which intern calls the testcase based on method name from excel sheet

I hope from above 2 approaches I am able to explain what I want to do. If anyone can provide a better solution I would really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do that. I have worked on similar kind of framework. Hope this information helps,

Framework type  :  `Cucumber + POM`

**Main sheet**: We keep all the test cases (tag names) in `Excel#1` and separate columns for required information like,

- Test case name(tag name)
- Test id (Example: Test01, Test02 etc.)
- Test case needs be executed or not.
- Data location of test case(Like excel name and sheet name). It's another excel where its stores all the necessary information which will be used to execute a test case.
- Browser type

```
    |Test case id |   Name      |  Location           | Browser type |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |Test01       |Test case 01 | Wb=Data;Sheet=Login | Chrome       |
    |Test02       |Test case 02 | Wb=Data;Sheet=Login | Edge         |
    |Test03       |Test case 03 | Wb=Data;Sheet=Login | Firefox      |
    |..
```

**Code**:

- Reads the main sheet and stores all the information in a `Map`
- Loads the data sheet based on the given location.
- Checks for test id in that sheet and loads the data of that row when test id matches.
- Execution starts from here.

**Data sheet**: As I said earlier, data sheet also should have same test id like main sheet. Listing out few columns of data sheet,

- URL
- Credentials
- Required data fields.
- Any external files (like json) location.
- etc.

```
   |Test case id |   Name      |  URL           | UserName | Password |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
   |Test01       |Test case 01 | http:\\...com  | Nandan1  | 12456    |
   |Test02       |Test case 02 | http:\\...com  | Nandan2  | 12456    |
   |Test03       |Test case 03 | http:\\...com  | Nandan3  | 12456    |
   |..
```

Comment: Thank you for writing @nandan-a, this is pretty helpful. But could you also through some light on how to read browser details of each test and then run at least 3-5 tests in parallel on different browsers. May be some kind of code sample would also help like how you extracted value of test case browser and then initialised that specific browser and run at least 3-5 tests in paralle?

Comment: We used `maven-surefire-plugin` for parallel execution. You can refer these articles, https://ghchirp.tech/464/ for parallel execution with `Junit` and https://ghchirp.tech/466/ for parallel execution with `TestNG`

Comment: You can refer this as well.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839885/java-sellinum-cucumber-excell-data-driven/68878883#68878883